# Filtering events by date in Swift4

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I'm building an application that provides autistic children with a very simple visual calendar based on scheduled events. So far, I've had no major issues and my events are filtering correctly when the first one is added for each recurrence frequency (daily, weekly, monthly, yearly).

However, for some reason, when I attempt to add a second event with a recurrence frequency that matches any events previously added, it will not populate.

I have attempted to debug and narrow down the issue myself to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something extremely simple. Thank you in advance for any assistance tracking this down.

This function filters the entire list of dates by date:

```
func filterEvents() {
    filteredEvents = []
    tempEvents = []
    dates = []

    removeOldEvents()
    generateRecurrances()
    extractDates()

    var currentIndex = 0

    for date in dates {
        if filteredEvents.count == 0 {
            filteredEvents.append([])
        }

        else if filteredEvents.count != currentIndex + 1 {
            filteredEvents.append([])
        }

        filteredEvents[currentIndex] = tempEvents.filter({ $0.filterDate() == date })

        currentIndex += 1
    }
}
```

This function is used to extract the necessary information to filter by date:

```
func extractDates() {
    for event in tempEvents {
        let extractedDate: (month: Int, day: Int, year: Int) = (event.month(), event.day(), event.year())

        dates.append(extractedDate)
    }

    var currentIndex = 0

    for date in dates {
        if currentIndex != 0 {
            if date.month == dates[currentIndex - 1].month && date.day == dates[currentIndex - 1].day && date.year == dates[currentIndex - 1].year {
                dates.remove(at: currentIndex)
                currentIndex -= 1
            }
        }

        currentIndex += 1
    }
}
```

This function generates recurring future events based on the user's preference when creating the original event:

```
func generateRecurrances() {
    var dateComponent = DateComponents()
    var daysToAdd = 0
    var weeksToAdd = 0
    var monthsToAdd = 0
    var yearsToAdd = 0

    for event in events {
        if event.recurrenceFrequency == 1 {
            for _ in 1...60 {
                dateComponent.day = daysToAdd
                dateComponent.month = 0
                dateComponent.year = 0

                let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: event.date)

                tempEvents.append(Event(name: event.name, date: newDate!, image: event.image, completion: event.requiresCompletion, recurrenceFrequency: event.recurrenceFrequency))

                daysToAdd += 1
            }
        }

        else if event.recurrenceFrequency == 2 {
            for _ in 1...8 {
                dateComponent.day = weeksToAdd
                dateComponent.month = 0
                dateComponent.year = 0

                let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: event.date)

                tempEvents.append(Event(name: event.name, date: newDate!, image: event.image, completion: event.requiresCompletion, recurrenceFrequency: event.recurrenceFrequency))

                weeksToAdd += 7
            }
        }

        else if event.recurrenceFrequency == 3 {
            for _ in 1...2 {
                dateComponent.day = 0
                dateComponent.month = monthsToAdd
                dateComponent.year = 0

                let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: event.date)

                tempEvents.append(Event(name: event.name, date: newDate!, image: event.image, completion: event.requiresCompletion, recurrenceFrequency: event.recurrenceFrequency))

                monthsToAdd += 1
            }
        }

        else if event.recurrenceFrequency == 4 {
            for _ in 1...2 {
                dateComponent.day = 0
                dateComponent.month = 0
                dateComponent.year = yearsToAdd

                let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: event.date)

                tempEvents.append(Event(name: event.name, date: newDate!, image: event.image, completion: event.requiresCompletion, recurrenceFrequency: event.recurrenceFrequency))

                yearsToAdd += 1
            }
        }

        else if event.recurrenceFrequency == 0 {
            tempEvents.append(event)
        }
    }

    daysToAdd = 0
}
```

I really don't think this is related but, just for safety, here is the function that is used to automatically remove events with a date prior to the current date:

```
func removeOldEvents() {
    var currentIndex = 0

    let now = Event(name: "Now", date: Date(), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo"), completion: false, recurrenceFrequency: 0)

    for event in events {
        if event.year() < now.year() {
            events.remove(at: currentIndex)

            currentIndex -= 1
        }

        else if event.month() < now.month() {
            events.remove(at: currentIndex)

            currentIndex -= 1
        }

        else if event.day() < now.day() {
            events.remove(at: currentIndex)

            currentIndex -= 1
        }

        currentIndex += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code to remove array elements is screwy. If the first item in an array needs to be removed it won't be. Why not just used `Array.filter()` to create a filtered version of your array?

Comment: If you're referring to the removeOldEvents() function, it's actually performing as desired. I am calling .filter() in the filterEvents() function. The issue isn't that old events aren't being removed. My problem is events of a particular recurrence frequency aren't properly populating after the first event of the same frequency is added. For example, if I add an event that is to recur on a daily basis, the first one populates correctly. If I add a second event to recur on a daily basis, the second event does not properly populate.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. You're referring to extractDates() and you're absolutely right. I'm working on fixing this now but still having a bit of a struggle. Any additional advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This modification to extractDates() has resolved this issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

```
func extractDates() {
    for event in tempEvents {
        dates.append(event.date)
    }

    var currentIndex = 0

    for date in dates {
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        dates[currentIndex] = newDate
        print(dates[currentIndex])
        currentIndex += 1
    }

    var tempDates = dates.removingDuplicates()
    tempDates = tempDates.sorted()
    dates = tempDates

    for date in dates {
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

        dateComponents.append((month, day, year))
    }
}
```